# how to fix this error in the strategy script

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, indicator

help me fix the error in the strategy script 
***"Script could not be translated from:|B|a:=n < length"***. 
The error, it seems to me, occurs in the last line of the first indicator. It seems to me that this is an integrator string.[enter link description here](http://www.pinecoders.com/techniques/dsp/) 
Separately without a strategy, indicators are compiled without problems.

```
strategy("Strategy long ", overlay=true)

//study("Trend Step")
length = input(50)
src = close
dev = stdev(src,length)*2
a = 0.
a := n < length ? src : src > nz(a[1],src) + dev ? src : src < nz(a[1],src) - dev ? src : a[1]

//study("Slowema")
slow_ema_period = input(20,"Slow EMA Period")
avg_price = input(hlc3)
smooth_length = input(5, minval=1)
fast_end = input(2.5,step=.5)
slow_end = input(20)
abs_noise = abs(avg_price - avg_price[1])
noise = sum(abs_noise, smooth_length)
signal = abs(avg_price - avg_price[smooth_length])
smooth = pow(iff(noise != 0, signal / noise, 0) * (2/(fast_end + 1) - 2/(slow_end + 1)) + 2/(slow_end + 1), 2) 
avg_ma = nz(avg_ma[1]) + smooth * (avg_price - nz(avg_ma[1]))
ha_symbol = heikinashi(tickerid)
ha_close = security(ha_symbol, period, avg_ma)
slow_ema = ema(ha_close,slow_ema_period)

plot(a,color=color.lime,linewidth=2,transp=0)
plot(slow_ema,color=yellow,linewidth=2,style=line)

//Strategy
longCondition =  crossover(a,slow_ema) 
closeCondition = crossunder(a,slow_ema)
strategy.entry("long",strategy.long,when = longCondition)
strategy.close("long",when = closeCondition)
```

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, do you just copy random pieces of code, put them together and then throw the result here? I see there three different versions of pine in your script. Of course after such approach you get such strange errors. Could you pay a bit respect to other people and write your own code or at least learn a bit about pine programming?
First and the main problem is redundant code `a = 0.`. It should be just
`a = n < length ... etc`

The second problem:
`color.lime` should be `lime`

Comment: no, I don’t do anything that seems to you pointless and just copy and paste ... as a beginner, I really see the code writing and run into a problem, then just ask for help

Comment: and why did you see 3 different versions of pine? there is only 3 version

Comment: thanks for the help! helped compile. I am grateful to you!

Comment: version 3 must have `//@version=3` at the very beginning. Otherwise it's version 1. `color.lime` - is version 4: before it colors didn't have prefix `color.`